# How to scan multiple words using sscanf in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to scan a line that contains multiple words in C. Is there a way to scan it word by word and store each word as a different variable?

For example, I have the following types of lines:

```
A is the 1 letter;
B is the 2 letter;
C is the 3 letter;
```

If I'm parsing through the first line: "A is the 1 letter" and I have the following code, what do I put in each case so I can get the individual tokens and store them as variables. To clarify, by the end of this code, I want "is," "the," "1," "letter" in different variables.

I have the following code:

```
while (feof(theFile) != 1) {
    string = "A is the 1 letter"
    first_word = sscanf(string);
    switch(first_word):
      case "A":
        what to put here?
      case "B":
        what to put here?
      ...
```

Comment: What delimits the words? Just a single space or spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `feof()` like that.  You should use `fgets()` or equivalent.  You probably need to use the little-known (but present in standard C89) conversion specifier `%n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        char *str = buffer;
        char word[256];
        int  posn;
        while (sscanf(str, "%255s%n", word, &posn) == 1)
        {
            printf("Word: <<%s>>\n", word);
            str += posn;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This reads a line, then uses `sscanf()` iteratively to fetch words from the line.  The `%n` format specifier doesn't count towards the successful conversions, hence the comparison with 1.  Note the use of `%255s` to prevent overflows in `word`. Note too that `sscanf()` could write a null after the 255 count specified in the conversion specification, hence the difference of one between the declaration of `char word[256];` and the conversion specifier `%255s`.

Clearly, it is up to you to decide what to do with each word as it is extracted; the code here simply prints it.

One advantage of this technique over any solution based on `strtok()` is that `sscanf()` does not modify the input string so if you need to report an error, you have the original input line to use in the error report.

---

After editing the question, it seems that the punctuation like semi-colon is not wanted in a word; the code above would include punctuation as part of the word.  In that case, you have to think a bit harder about what to do.  The starting point might well be using and alphanumeric scan-set as the conversion specification in place of `%255s`:

```
"%255[a-zA-Z_0-9]%n"
```

You probably then have to look at what's in the character at the start of the next component and skip it if it is not alphanumeric:

```
if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*str))
{
    if (sscanf(str, "%*[^a-zA-Z_0-9]%n", &posn) == 0)
        str += posn;
}
```

Leading to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        char *str = buffer;
        char word[256];
        int  posn;
        while (sscanf(str, "%255[a-zA-Z_0-9]%n", word, &posn) == 1)
        {
            printf("Word: <<%s>>\n", word);
            str += posn;
            if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*str))
            {
                if (sscanf(str, "%*[^a-zA-Z_0-9]%n", &posn) == 0)
                    str += posn;
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

You'll need to consider the I18N and L10N aspects of the alphanumeric ranges chosen; what's available may depend on your implementation (POSIX doesn't specify support in [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) scan-sets for the notations such as `[[:alnum:]]`, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok()` to tokenize or split strings. Please refer the following link for an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

You can take array of character pointers and assign tokens to them.

Example:

```
char *tokens[100];
int i = 0;
char *token = strtok(string, " ");
while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[i] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}

printf("Total Tokens: %d", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the `%s` specifier strips whitespace. So you can write:

```
    std::string s = "A is the 1 letter";
    typedef char Word[128];
    Word words[6];
    int wordsRead = sscanf(s.c_str(), "%128s%128s%128s%128s%128s%128s", words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5] );
    std::cout << wordsRead << " words read" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0;
        i != wordsRead;
        ++i)
        std::cout << "'" << words[i] << "'" << std::endl;
```

Note how this approach (unlike `strtok`), effectively requires an assumption about the maximim number of words to read, as well as their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `strtok()`. 
Here is the example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

`Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:`

`This`

`a`

`sample`

`string`